# Snappy-java uncompress fails for valid data

Tags: scala, akka, snappy

I am trying to uncompress the bytestring using snappy-java

```
ByteString(0xff, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x73, 0x4e, 0x61, 0x50, 0x70, 0x59, 1, 14, 0, 0, 38, -104, 43, -49, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 79, 75)
```

It contains two frames, first with chunk value 0xff(stream identifier) and length 6 and second frame of chunk type 1(uncompressed), with length 14. Which is valid as per protocol spec found [here] (http://code.google.com/p/snappy/source/browse/trunk/framing_format.txt)

The code used to uncompress is here

```
val c = ByteString(0xff, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x73, 0x4e, 0x61, 0x50, 0x70, 0x59, 1, 14, 0, 0, 38, -104, 43, -49, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 79, 75)
Snappy.uncompress(c.toArray)
```

The code throws FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS error, which is part of jna. I am using scala v2.11.3 and snappy-java v1.0.5.4

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.throw_error(SnappyNative.java:78)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(Native Method)
at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.rawUncompress(Snappy.java:395)
at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:431)
at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:407)
```

Comment: Is the checksum for the uncompressed data correct?

Comment: The checksum is correct. I got the issue resolved. The problem is with using Snappy.uncompress. After the framing format is standardized in snappy, SnappyFramedInputStream is created to deal with framed messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Failed to uncompress error is because Snappy.uncompress does not support framed input. The framing format is finalized recently and the implemented is added in SnappyFramedInputStream. The source is located [here](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/xerial/snappy/SnappyFramedInputStream.java)

The following is the code to decompress snappy frames

```
def decompress(contents: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
    val is = new SnappyFramedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(contents))
    val os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(Snappy.uncompressedLength(contents))
    is.transferTo(os)
    os.close()
    os.toByteArray
}
```